# what's the difference between search_after and range query in elasticsearch

Tags: elasticsearch

It seems that `search_after` is equivalent to `{range:{"gt":xxx}}` when used in iterating an index.

I wander that's their difference in terms of semantics and performance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They serve different purposes. With `search_after` you can paginate over 10K results (whatever the query), whereas the `range` query will only allow you to select a subset of your index and if there are more than 10K documents matching that range, you'll not be able to get them all.

Comment: Get it. But when is comes to iterating, is there any difference between the two methods?

Comment: Without `search_after` you cannot iterate past 10K results. So you can "iterate" with range, but you'll need to find ranges that contain less than 10K documents, and since all ranges might not be equal in terms of how many documents they filter, you'll never know in advance what range you can pick on each iteration. Said differently, `range` is not meant for iterating